# How to run installation CD for second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, live-cd, cd

I am running ubuntu 14 off of a live USB.  I have a second monitor that I would like to use while using ubuntu.  It has an installation cd that you have to install before using, and when I click on the .exe file the Archive Manager tries to open it and says an error occurred while loading the archive.  Thanks for the help.

---

Edit: additional information

It just doesn't show up when when I'm in the display settings area. I press the locate(name is probably something else) monitor button too. I know it needs the CD because when I was using it with Windows it didn't work until I went through the installation process on the CD. If ubuntu doesn't use .exe files is there a way to use the CD still?

Monitor info from label: -acer LCD monitor -model number: S200HQL Version: S200HQL bd

I connect it to my computer using a VGA cord which is connected to a j5create VGA to USB adapter.

Not sure if this helps: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

```
lsusb output: Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bc2:2100 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0711:5200 Magic Control Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: That's because Ubuntu doesn't use `.exe` files.

Comment: Does the monitor not work when you connect it? Usually such installation CDs don't contain much more than colour profiles, and you could try out some of the built-in ones if you do need them.

Comment: It just doesn't show up when when I'm in the display settings area.  I press the locate(name is probably something else) monitor button too.  I know it needs the CD because when I was using it with Windows it didn't work until I went through the installation process on the CD.  If ubuntu doesn't use .exe files is there a way to use the CD still?

Comment: Windows is not Ubuntu. Just because it didn't work in Windows without a CD, doesn't mean that's the same in Ubuntu. Maybe there is an issue with your display drivers instead. You should provide as much information as possible (Ubuntu version, graphics chipset, what monitors you're using, and their connection type).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Like dobey says, we need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Your question seems perfectly valid to me.  Sorry that you haven't had any good responses so far.

Comment: We need more details to help.  The CD for almost any product doesn't contain drivers that are usable in Linux. Windows yes, Mac maybe but any other OS almost never. What is the monitor, how is it connected and what graphics card does your computer have?

Comment: I provided all of the info requested in these comments in an edit I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with **the j5create VGA to USB adapter**

It looks like this needs a driver and there is no driver for it. [There is an old thread in another forum.](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/vga-to-usb-dual-monitor-4175476917/) They didn't find any solution and the OP there ended up buying a new graphics card that can handle two monitors. Also see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195279 for another person failing to make this work.

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

- Most likely, the installation CD that came with your monitor is *incompatible with Linux*.  This means than you won't be able to run that CD.
- Most likely, you do not need to run the installation CD in order to use the monitor.  When I buy a monitor, I throw the installation CD directly into the garbage without opening it - regardless of the OS I use.
- With Linux, you don't typically install drivers that came bundled on the CD of a piece of hardware.  Linux itself already contains support for thousands upon thousands of pieces of hardware without the need to install any drivers (in this sense it has an advantage over Windows - when it works).  The general philosophy with the Linux kernel is that it should support as much existing hardware as possible without the need for extra drivers.  When you *do* need to install extra drivers, often you'll be able to get them through Ubuntu-specific means rather than from the original manufacturer of the hardware.  A Google search (eg for `ubuntu model-name-of-hardware`) will also often be helpful.

  That said, for a monitor you don't usually need to run the installer, regardless of whether you're running Linux or Windows.  Those installers don't usually install a driver as such (although it could be a "driver" that consists mainly of a color profile), just some software you probably won't use.